# How to find if UILabel text is shortened/shrinked?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uilabel

I'm working on application for iOS (iPhone and iPad), and I have a UILabel on my view that displays some text. If the text is too long, UILabel automatically shrink it, for example:

"This is some long text" will display "This is some..."

This behaviour is correct, totally acceptable, and even expected, but I would like to know if the text was shortened or not. Is there any way to find if UILabel has shortened its content?

I need really simple solution, because I would like to use UILabel magic functionality like automatically reducing font size to fit etc. Sometimes the text will be just very long, so I will give user a way to see it all in another view after taping a button. But in the case the text wont be so long, I would like to hide that button to make interface simple.
Any idea how to achieve this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Ask the label's text it's length at the label's standard font. If that's longer than the label's width, it will be drawn smaller to fit.

```
CGSize stringSize = [aLabel.text sizeWithFont:aLabel.font];
if (stringSize.width > aLabel.frame.size.width) {
        // It's drawing the label with a reduced font.
}
```

Note: This is an old answer. As Apple updates their APIs, some things must change. The basic technique still works, but the method call used should be updated. See Vins answer for an update.

Answer (score 3):

In iOS 7, sizeWithFont is deprecated.

```
CGSize stringSize = [aLabel.text sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: aLabel.font}];
    if (stringSize.width > aLabel.frame.size.width) {
            // It's drawing the label with a reduced font.
    }
```

if label is multiline:

```
CGSize stringSize = [aLabel.text sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: aLabel.font}];
    if (stringSize.width > aLabel.frame.size.width*numOfLines) {
            // It's drawing the label with a reduced font.
     }
```